# Why does fetestexcept() sometimes complain when multiplying floats?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I am using [fetestexcept()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fetestexcept.html) in C99 and it sometimes complains about multiplying floats gives an inexact result ([FE_INEXACT](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/fenv.h.html)). It seems to happen when multiplying float variables with float literals. How can I modify this so fetestexcept() will not complain ?

gcc -std=c99 -lm test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main(void)
{
    float a = 1.1f;
    float b = 1.2f;
    float c = a * b * 1.3f;

    int exception = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    if(exception != 0)
    {
        printf("Exception: 0x%x\n", exception); // 0x20 FE_INEXACT
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, don't test for FE_INEXACT if you're not interested in that exception? E.g. instead of

```
int exception = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
```

do

```
int exception = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT & ~FE_INEXACT);
```

Comment: But why does it happen only when using float variables ?

Comment: @JaneS: Because the FPU signals exceptions only for floating point operations ? Or what do you mean?

Comment: I mean <b>float c = a * b * 1.3f;</b> gives the exception but not <b>float c = 1.1f * 1.2f * 1.3f;</b>

Comment: One guess could be that the version of GCC that you're using doesn't signal FP exceptions when constant folding. Or that you're compiling for 32-bit x86, and the x87 excess precision issue rears its ugly head. In any case, you almost certainly don't want to check for FP_INEXACT unless you're doing something very particular, since more or less anything nontrivial you do will signal that exception.

Comment: GCC computes constant expressions at compile time. Because `c` is just set at run time to the precomputed value, no loss of precision occurs. If you define the constants as `static const float A = 1.1f, B = 1.2f, C = 1.3f;` and compile with `-O0` (no optimizations), then GCC actually performs the multiplication `float c = A * B * C;`, and `FP_INEXACT` gets raised. With default optimizations GCC sees that `A`, `B`, and `C` are all constants, and precomputes the value into `c`, turning it from a multiplication into a plain assignment. You can see this if you compile to assembly `-S`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Diagnostic-Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) to ignore certian warnings.

For example, if I were to compile a subset of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <fenv.h>  
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON  
int main(void) {
   float a = 1.1f;
   float b = 1.2f;
   float c = a * b * 1.3f;
   int exception = c;
   return 0;
 }
```

With:

```
gcc -Wall test.c
```

I'd get a bunch of warnings like:

```
test.c:22:0: warning: ignoring #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS [-Wunknown-pragmas]
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:28:11: warning: unused variable ‘exception’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Then to silence them you can add the "ignored" pragmas:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
```

Recompile and the warnings go away.